# Hovertemplate does not recognize the text vector I pass to it

Tags: r, plotly

I create the bar chart below using `plotly` but while I give values to `text` it is not recognized in my `hovertemplate`.

```
library(plotly)
    "Country(s)"<-c("United Kingdom", "Brazil", "United States Of America", "India", 
      "Russian Federation")
    "Number of cases"<-c(1032990, 1264637, 5905072, 618694, 735681)
    "lab"<-c("1.0M", "1.3M", "5.9M", "618.7K", "735.7K")
    cm4d<-data.frame(`Country(s)`,`Number of cases`,lab)
    
    fig1 <- plot_ly(cm4d, x = ~`Country(s)`, y = ~`Number of cases`,text=~lab,
                    type = 'bar',
                    hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>Number of cases: %{text}<br><extra></extra>'),
                    colors = c("#60ab3d","#6bbabf","#c4d436","#3e5b84","#028c75"),
                    color = ~`Country(s)`)
    fig1
```

while this works

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

full_data<-data.frame("Name"=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q1","Q2","Q3"),"Values"=c(245645,866556,26440,65046,641131,463265),
                      "Week"=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"))
desc <- full_data %>% 
  group_by(Name,Week) %>% 
  summarise(values = sum(Values)) %>%
  mutate(lab = scales::label_number_si(accuracy = 0.1)(values))


fig1 <- plot_ly(desc, x = ~`Name`, y = ~values,text = ~lab,
                type = 'bar',
                hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>Number of cases: %{text}<br><extra></extra>'),
                colors = c("#60ab3d","#6bbabf","#c4d436"),
                color = ~Name)
fig1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this is an "answer". I think you ran into a bug! It seems like `{plotly}` expects a "stacked" bar chart.

You can quickly make your working solution "fail" when you limit the desc dataframe to single rows only.

```
fig2 <- plot_ly(desc[c(1,3,5), ]
               , x = ~`Name`, y = ~values,text = ~lab
               , type = 'bar'
               , hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>Number of cases: %{text}<br><extra></extra>'),
                colors = c("#60ab3d","#6bbabf","#c4d436"),
                color = ~Name)
fig2
```

With such a "single key element" dataframe, fig2 shows the annoying `%text` in the hovertext!

I have not yet found a way to circumnavigate this.

Comment: thanks this may be an issue that plotly devs should  look at

Comment: I think so. If you file a bug report, provide a link to this post and/or your story/experience